# Error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I wrote the following Package and Package body:

```
create or replace package discounts
is
g_id number := 7839;
discount_rate number := 0.0;
procedure display_price(p_price number);
end;
/
create or replace package body discounts
is
procedure display_price(p_price number)
is
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate 1:'||discount_rate); 
     dbms_output.put_line('Discounted '||to_char(p_price * nvl(discount_rate,0)));
     dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate 2:'||discount_rate); 
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate 3:'||discount_rate); 
  discount_rate := 0.10;
  dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate 4:'||discount_rate); 
end;
/
```

It is written that "The value of discount_rate is set to 0.10 when the package is invoked for the first time in a session". I am not getting this point exactly that's why I checked the value each time of discount rate. I typed the following to invoke:

```
SQL> execute discounts.display_price(1000);
Discount rate 3:0
Discount rate 4:.1
Discount rate 1:.1
Discounted 100
Discount rate 2:.1
```

Then again I invoked the variable:

```
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate :'||discounts.discount_rate);
  end;
  SQL> /
  Discount rate :.1
```

Then I typed "exit" to close the SQL *PLUS. Again I opened SQL *PLUS and typed the same code:

```
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate :'||discounts.discount_rate);
  end;
```

I thought it will not initialize the variable but I got the error:

```
  ERROR at line 3:
  ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
  := . ( % ;
  The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

What is the mistake ? I am new to PL/SQL preparing for certification exam.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I could not reproduce the error you showed:

```
C:\>sqlplus user/password

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Mar 23 11:31:19 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> execute discounts.display_price(1000);
Discount rate 3:0
Discount rate 4:.1
Discount rate 1:.1
Discounted 100
Discount rate 2:.1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate :'||discounts.discount_rate);
  3  end;
  4  /
Discount rate :.1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

C:\>sqlplus user/password

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Mar 23 11:31:50 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Discount rate :'||discounts.discount_rate);
  3  end;
  4  /
Discount rate 3:0
Discount rate 4:.1
Discount rate :.1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh ! just a silly mistake I did. I forgot to write ; symbol in dbms_output.put_line statement. Well thanks for helping.. :))

Comment: @ankitaP: So, basically, the code you put in your question wasn't the code that caused the error?

Comment: After pressing "exit" button, the code starting from 'begin' till 'end' is correct logically but I did not mention ; there when I was doing in my SQL *Plus and so the error came as exactly I wrote. But I did mention ; during when I asked here in stackoverflow. That is so silly of me :/